# iOS 9 get UILocalNotification on applicationDidFinishLaunching

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, uilocalnotification

In iOS 9 I can't able to access `UILocalNotification` when swipe on notification in lock screen.

It seems that `applicationDidFinishLaunching` not being called, this is the strange. I put a `NSLog` as first line of `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and it's printed on console only when I open the app by tapping on its icon.

Indeed, if I put this code in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and I swipe on notification in lock to open the app, neither `YES` or `NO` are printed.

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

NSLog(@"%@",(localNotification ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
```

More, when I swipe on the notification, this message was printed in console

```
SBLockScreenNotificationListController: Attempting to remove a bulletin I don't have
```

Ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

put this code in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`

```
if (launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey])
{
    UILocalNotification *notification = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    [self application:application didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

I hope it's work for you.

Comment: I'm looking for UILocalNotification, not remote notification

Comment: Where is the differences from your code and my code? It seems that code in `didFinishLaunching` is never executed.